# Why is this Array and join is always N-1?

Tags: javascript

When using `Array` with `join` it always returns `N-1` elements.  Here is what I mean. In javascript console I do the below.

```
    Array(2).join('*')  #=> "*"  but I was expecting "**"
new Array(1).join('*')  #=> ""   but I was expecting "*"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly is `Array(2)` supposed to be? A constructor call with argument `2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Join inserts strings **between** elements. So, how many "between" positions are there with `N` elements? Yes... `N-1`

Answer (score 0):

`Array(3)` will create an array of 3 `undefined` members: `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`, in which there are only 2 gaps, that's why `.join('*')` gives you `'**'`